# How to unescape QUERY_STRING in mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, escaping

Hi all,

Now I want to use mod_rewrite module in apache2 to redirect url.

The rewrite rule looks like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/redir$ %1 [R=301,L]
```

However, when http://website.com/redir?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com is input, the mod_rewrite module cannot unecsape the url parameter http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com, is there any method to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

```
RewriteMap unescape int:unescape

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/redir$ ${unescape:%1} [R=301,L]
```

Apache lets you define custom rewrite mappings from different types of external sources. For example, if you wanted to rewrite `/users/<some alias>` to `/users/<full name>`, you could have a text file that specified alias/name pairs, and a rewrite rule that translated the "alias" part of the URL using that mapping.

Mappings can come from multiple types of sources. The alias/name example is the standard plain text (`txt`) type.

`RewriteMap` also lets you map to a handful of special internal sources (`int`). They just pass the value to an internal Apache function and return the result. They are:

- `toupper`: Converts the key to all upper case.
- `tolower`: Converts the key to all lower case.
- `escape`: Translates special characters in the key to hex-encodings.
- `unescape`: Translates hex-encodings in the key back to special characters.

`unescape` is what you're looking for.

More information can be found in the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap).

Answer (score -2):

Yep, there is one method: give it to a `Php` file then make a redirection in `Php` with appropriate "`header`".

Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/redir$ /myredir.php?redir=%1 [R=301,L]
```

And in Php, in the file `myredir.php` something like:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['redir'])) {
    header("Location: ".urldecode($_GET['redir']));
}
exit;
?>
```

Comment: yes, this case is very easy for any dynamic script language. I think the performance will be best if implemented in the Apache sever level.

Comment: You're perfectly right. But performance isn't a problem unless you have thousands of thousands of thousands of thousands of thousands of visitors. If it's not the case, then this solution should be ok. Think of it: it's a "temporary solution" and if things go very well then I'll think of it once again. What I mean is: maybe it's too early to optimize *that* level. Sometimes you have more important things to do. And knowing that Php is compiled into bytecode, it stays in cache, I think that there is very few interest to try to gain some picoseconds.